# WPF - Set Unique ID for Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas

I am working in **WPF**. I have created array of `Canvas` and want to assign unique Id to each.

Is there any solution ?

Code:

```
private Canvas[] regionCanvas;
regionCanvas = new Canvas[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just make your own class which inherits from Canvas and make a property called id. That's an easy way to do it :)

and if you want your program to create the id yourself, you should implement an ID counter, that just increment by one each time you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question.

If you want to use a key to retrieve a specific canvas you can use a Dictionary

```
var canvasDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Canvas>();
canvasDictionary.Add("CanvasBackground", new Canvas());
canvasDictionary.Add("CanvasCharacter", new Canvas());
canvasDictionary.Add("CanvasEffects", new Canvas());
```

So, if you need the Canvas dedicated to the background:

```
var canvas = canvasDictionary["CanvasBackground"];
```

Hope this can help you